# Unable to run the spring-boot application as Ubuntu service

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, spring-boot

I followed the document from spring reference here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service to configure the executable .jar file as Ubuntu service, however I got an error

```
/etc/init.d/testapp: 1: /etc/init.d/testapp: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I'm not sure if spring boot executable script supports Ubuntu or not.

Comment: whats your spring boot version?

Comment: Show us the script. Which version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: Have you configured Boot's Maven or Gradle plugin to build a fully executable jar?

Comment: @AliDehghani: I', using Spring boot 1.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: @Marged: It's Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: I used Maven for configuration, and followed the Spring doc, added executable for spring-boot-maven-plugin artifact

Comment: I have a similar problem with FreeBSD (spring boot 1.2.8)
 /usr/local/etc/rc.d/authorization: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected